# Maximum Turns in Hamiltonian Cycle on Even Grids

Tags: graph-theory

Can you provide the specific formula for calculating the maximum number of turns in a Hamiltonian cycle on an m×n lattice graph, given that m and n are both even numbers greater than 2?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Relevant older post?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58904/maximum-number-of-turns-on-a-hamiltonian-cycle

Comment: Following an additional link under dbal's thread, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.08800.pdf) appears to provide the answer.