# Prove $\,b\equiv c\pmod{\!m}\Rightarrow \gcd(b,m)=\gcd(c,m)$ i.e. $\gcd(c+km,m) = \gcd(c,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $ b\equiv c \pmod m $ then prove that $(b,m)=(c,m)$.

My solution so far:

If $b \equiv c \pmod m$ then $c = b - sm$ for some $s$. Now if $d = (b, m)$
then $ d |  (b + s m)$.

Comment: If an answer is good enough to accept, is it not also good enough to upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(b,m) = d$ and $(c,m) = d'$. If $b \equiv c \pmod m$ then $b = c + \lambda m$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$. We know that $d|b$ and $d|m$, so $d|(b-\lambda m)$ and so $d|c$ and hence $d|d'$.

Can you see where to take it from here?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\,d\:|\:m\:$  then $\rm\:d\:|\:b\!\iff\! d\:|\:c,\:$ by $\rm\:b\equiv c\pmod{\! d},\,$ by $\rm\,d\:|\:m\:|\:b\!-\!c$

Therefore $\rm\,m,b,\,$ and $\rm\,m,c\,$ have the same set $\,\rm S\,$ of *common* divisors $\rm\,d,\,$ so they necessarily  have the same *greatest* common divisor $\rm (= \max\:\! S)$

**Remark** $\ $Alternatively, we may use the Bezout characterization of the gcd $\rm\,(m,b)\,$ as the least positive integer in $\rm\: m\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z. \,$ Thus $\rm\:(m,b) = (m,c)\:$ follows from $\rm\: m\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z\, =\, m\,\Bbb Z + c\,\Bbb Z,\,$
true by $\rm\  m\:j+ \color{#c00}bk = m\:j + (\color{#c00}{b\!-\!c})k + \color{#c00}ck = m\,(j+k(b\!-\!c)/m) + ck = m j' + ck,\:$ so $\rm\:m\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z \,\subseteq\, m\,\Bbb Z + c\,\Bbb Z,\:$ and the reverse inclusion follows by $\rm\,b\leftrightarrow c\,$ symmetry.

In terms of ideal theory this may be viewed simply as a standard "change of basis", cf. [Remark here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533044/242)

Comment: $mj + (b-c)k + ck = m(j + k(b-c)/m) + ck$. How do you reach the right side of this?

Comment: Also how to interpret this $\rm\:m\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z \subset m\,\Bbb Z + c\,\Bbb Z.\:$?

Comment: @Michael That inclusion means every integer of the form $\rm\,m\,j+b\,k,\ \ j,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ can be written as $\rm\,m\,j'+c\,k',\ \ j',k'\in\Bbb Z.\,$ The rhs arises by factoring $\rm m$ out of $\rm\,b\!-\!c,\,$ i.e. $\rm\, (b\!-\!c)k = m(k(b\!-\!c)/m)$  $\ \ \ \ $ $\ \  \ \ $

Comment: Ok, but specifically how to interpret the proper subset notation?

Comment: @Michael $\ \rm m\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z := \{ m\,j + b\,k\ :\ j,k\in\Bbb Z\}\,$ denotes a *set* so it is normal set inclusion notation.

Comment: But $\subset$ implies that the left set has less elements than the right one. By which logic?

Comment: @Michael Not for *infinite* sets, e.g. $\, 2\Bbb Z\subsetneq \Bbb Z\ $ but both have the same size (cardinality).

Comment: I cant seem to wrap my head around this. Can you please show an example of this proper subset with actual numbers for this specific case?

Comment: @Michael e.g. above  the even integers are a proper subset of the integers but they have the same cardinality. If you're not familiar with cardinality of (infinite)  sets then there are surely many explanations in answers on MSE. e.g. [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339190/242).

Comment: I know about that, but I meant for you to show the one from the answer with linear combination. Surely the left set will have elements that are not part of the right set, or?

Comment: I mean if any integer that can be written in the first form can also be written in the second then those sets contain exactly the same integers, right? So what makes the first set a proper subset of second, where is the difference?

Comment: @Michael No it means that all those of first form are a subset of all those of 2nd form. It seems you are interpreting $\ S\subset T\,$ in the answer as denoting a *proper* subset. But there it only means subset (the notation is used both ways). I'll edit it to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: So those 2 sets are in fact the same?

Comment: @Michael Yes, the answer proves one inclusion and the reverse inclusion follows by symmetry. Thus they have the same least positive element (= gcd). In fact both $\rm = d\,\Bbb Z\,$ where $\rm\,d = (b,m) = (c,m)\ \ $

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $b\equiv c\pmod{m}$.

Suppose that  $x$ divides both $b$ and $m$. Since $c=b+km$ for some $k$, it follows that $x$ divides $c$.

Similarly, if $x$ divides both $c$ and $m$, then $x$ divides $b$.

Thus every common divisor of $b$ and $m$ is a common divisor of $c$ and $m$, and vice-versa.

It follows that the **greatest** common divisor of $b$ and $m$ is the same as the greatest common divisor of $c$ and $m$.

Answer (score 3):

You pointed out that $b=c+sm$ for some $s$.

Let $d=bx+my$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z},\;\;d\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $d=cx'+my'$ for $x'=x,\;\;y'=y+sx$. Similarly  if $d=cx+my$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z},\;\;d\in \mathbb{N}$ then $d=bx'+my'$ for $x'=x,\;\;y'=y-sx$.

Bearing in mind that $(b,m)=\min\{bx+my:x,y\in \mathbb{Z},bx+my>0\}$ the result follows.