# Two numbers being coprime implies other two numbers being coprime

Tags: number-theory

Let $b$, $m$, $p$ be positive integers such that $b > p$. And suppose that $mb+p$ and $b$ are coprime. Then I have to show that $mb+p$ and $b-p$ are also coprime.

I tried myself but it seems trickier than I expected, as most number theoretic problems are.... Could anyone please help me?

Comment: A common divisor divides $b$ and $mb+p$, hence also $p$. So ...

Comment: So with $p=5$, $b=7$, $m=1$, the claim is that if $12$ and $7$ are coprime, then so are $12$ and $2$?

Comment: More broadly, if $m,p,b$ are all odd then $mb+p$ and $b-p$ are both even so you can generate  lot of counterexamples.

Comment: I see...thank you for enlightening me of my error...

Answer (score 2):

$1 = (mb\!+\!p,b) = (p,b)\,$  by Euclidean reductions, and similarly   $\ \,\phantom{\^{|^|}}(mb\!+\!p,b\!-\!p) = (mp\!+\!p,b\!-\!p) = (m\!+\!1,b\!-\!p),\,$ by $\,(p,b\!-\!p)= (p,b) = 1$

But it is easy to make $(m\!+\!1,b\!-\!p)>1,\,$ e.g. choose coprime $b,p$ with $b\!-\!p>1$ and $m\!+\!1 = b\!-\!p,\,$ e.g. $\,b,p = 7,5,\ m = b\!-\!p\!-\!1 = 1\,$ (Hagen's counterexample). There are infinitely many more.

**Therefore** $ $ if $\,(mb\!+\!p,b) = 1\,$ then $\,(mb\!+\!p,b\!-\!p)=1\iff (m\!+\!1,b\!-\!p)=1$

**Update** $ $ Per request in comments below is further detail.

[By Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192472/242) $\ y'\equiv y\pmod{\! x}\,\Rightarrow\, (x,y') = (x,y)$

$\!\bmod b\!-\!p\!:\,\ b\equiv p\,\Rightarrow\, mb\!+\!p\equiv mp\!+\!p,\,$ so by above

we deduce $\ (b\!-\!p,\, mb\!+\!p) = (b\!-\!p,\,mp\!+\!p)= (b\!-\!p,\,p(m\!+\!1))$

but $\,(b\!-\!p,p)= (b,p) = 1\,$ so $\,(b\!-\!p,\,p(m\!+\!1)) = (b\!-\!p,\,m\!+\!1)$

Comment: Can you explain the equalities after 'and similarly'?

Comment: @Michael See the Update.

Comment: Ok, can you please also explain the last line?

Comment: @Michael It's case $\,(a,p)=1\,$ in $\,(a,pn) = (a,(a,p)n),\,$ by $\,(a,pn) = (a,an,pn) = (a,(a,p)n)$ $\ \ \ $

Comment: Why is $(a,pn) = (a,an,pn)$?

Comment: @Michael $\ d\mid a,b\iff d\mid a,an,b,\ $ by $\,d\mid a\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid an\ \ $

Comment: One more thing, $(b-p,p) =(b,p)$?

Comment: @Michaeal That too is "By Euclid..." since $\, b-p\equiv b\pmod{p}.\ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192472/242) for a proof. This is the congruence version of the modular reduction step in the Euclidean algorithm.