# Intuitive understanding of ideal $I = (x+1,x^2+1)$ and the quotient $\Bbb Z[x]/I$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

For a principal ideal, I have a good understanding of what it will look like in terms of making all multiples of the ideal $0$ (gluing them with zero). I don't on the other hand have any intuition of what $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+1,x^{2}+1)$$ will look like, I believe it contains $\mathbb{Z}/(x+1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(x^{2}+1)$ but apart from that I don't know. I believe it’s $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\!\bmod I=(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!a},f(x),g(x),\ldots)\!:\ \color{#c00}{x\equiv a}\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}x)\equiv f(\color{#c00}a),\, g(\color{#c00}x)\equiv g(\color{#c00}a),\,\ldots$

therefore: $\,\ I = (x\!-\!a,f(a),g(a),\ldots),\ $ where we used the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

So, in OP: $\, \ I = (x\!+\!1,\, x^2\!+1) = (x\!+\!1,\,\color{#0a0}2)\ $ since $\,f(x)=x^2+1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{f(-1) = 2}$

So $\,\Bbb Z[x]/I = \Bbb Z[x]/(x\!+\!1,2)\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(x\!+\!1)/((2,x\!+\!1)/(x\!+\!1) \cong \Bbb Z/2\,$ via Third Isom. theorem.

**Remark** $ $ Above is a sort of ideal form of the basic step in the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd, viz.
$$(h,f,g,\ldots) = (h,\, f\bmod h,\, g\bmod h,\ldots)$$

i.e. we can mod out all the other generators by any generator while preserving the ideal. More generally ideals are preserved under any [unimodular transformation of the generators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863501/242), which may be viewed as an ideal form of a "change of basis". The Euclidean algorithm generalizes in various ways, e.g. to Hermite (or Smith) normal forms, and other standard basis algorithms e.g. Grobner bases.

Such standard bases often yield a more "intuitive understanding" of the ideal, being "simpler" in various ways, e.g. they may be in triangular form and/or be a *module* basis, which makes it clear how to use the basis as effective normal-form rewriting rules (e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374203/242)), and may also make it easier to deduce properties of the quotient ring.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as imposing several conditions on the element $x$: if $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ with $I=(x+1,x^2+1)$, then $R$ is generated by some element $x$ which has to satisfy the two relations $x+1=0$ and $x^2+1=0$.

So in this case, we must have $x=-1$ by the first relation, but also $x^2=-1$, so $1=(-1)^2=-1$, which means that indeed $R$ must have characteristic $2$, and $x=1$. In the end, $R$ is the ring of characteristic $2$ generated by an element which is actually $1$, so it is $\mathbb{F}_2$ as you suspected.

Note that $R$ does not contain $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, it is a quotient of each of those rings (for instance, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, you you see it cannot be a subring of $R\simeq \mathbb{F}_2$).

Comment: very nice answer